# What is the max number of simple cycles in a directed graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, np

Is there a relation between edges and nodes? How could it be expressed in asymptotic notation?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If it's pure mathematics try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But before you post on another site you should check their help page to make sure the question is on topic and be sure to show your research and where you're stuck.

Comment: I post the question on math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108556/what-is-the-max-number-of-simple-cycles-in-a-directed-graph